# GCM - There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

For my iOS App I want to generate configutation files to support GCM.

On a [Google Developer's website](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add), I have to add the APNS Certificates (P12 format).

However, when I try to upload those certificates I have an error :

> **There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.**

Nothing more.

Certificates are created at the Apple developer site, added to the keychain,  and exported with private key, in p12 format (and even in pem format with command line).

I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Found solution... just create a new private key...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? Where do you do that exactly? Thanks